# When a gcp project is deleted, what happens to the associated objects in terraform state file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-sql, terraform-provider-gcp

Need help in understanding the terraform state file behavior.

I am working on a gcp project. We have multiple objects like gke cluster,redis etc., associated with the project. And all of these associated objects have their own terraform state files. We have manually deleted the gcp project. What will happen to the associated objects? Will they be deleted as well?

1. If the associated objects(gke cluster, redis etc.,) also gets deleted along with the gcp project, then how can I update all these manually deleted resources in terraform state file?
2. If the associated objects are not deleted, then how can I delete the resources using terraform config files without the gcp projectId??
3. If I create the same gcp project again in future, will it throw any error saying the projectId is already present since I deleted it manually?? or will it just recreate it??
4. Finally, since we have deleted the gcp project manually, if I just ignore updating the state files of the associated objects, will terraform allow me to create the same gcp project and associated objects again?

Comment: First of all, you are breaking the design of Terraform. You do not manage resources outside Terraform. If you delete a project, the project is not actually deleted for 30 days. That means you cannot reuse the Project ID during that time. If you delete the project you should also delete the Terraform state.

Comment: @JohnHanley do I need to delete all the associated objects in gcp project from terraform state files? also do I need to use CLI commands or use terraform config files to delete? And what order do I need to follow to delete the associated objects from the state files? If I create the same project again(without deleting the terraform state files) after 30 days will the creation be successful?? Tried researching my scenario but was not able to find much information.

Comment: Just delete the Terraform state files as in start over.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you so much for your suggestion. As you know we have many resources which are associated with the project in GCP and it is very hard to find list of the objects associated with the project and delete all their state files because we stored state files in s tree format structure like environment/region/resource not everything in a single state file. do you have any suggestion how can i delete all the resource state files associated with a single gcp project (which is deleted manually)

Comment: If you delete a project manually, then just delete everything in your terraform folder except for the HCL. None of it will be useful in the future. Then run **terraform init** to start again.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you. As per your suggestion, after deleting the GCS bucket state files manually, I was able to create the new project for all the associated objects.